# Creating several new vectors from an original vector with separators

Tags: r

I'm trying to create several vectors from an original vector.
I read some posts but couldn't find something to solve my problem.

My original vector is looking like this:

```
> orig_vec
[1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D;" "1"  "2;" "a1" "a2" "a3"
```

I want vectors that look like this:

```
> vector1
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
> vector2
[1] "1" "2"
> vector3
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
```

So what I need is a code which recognizes the semicolons as separators and creates new vectors depending on the number of separated values in "orig_vec".

I also have the problem that the "orig_vec" can change. 
When it looks like this:

```
> orig_vec
[1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "D"   "E;"  "1"   "2;"  "a1"  "a2"  "a3;" "b1"
```

I need to get automatically these vectors:

```
> vector1
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
> vector2
[1] "1" "2"
> vector3
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
> vector4
[1] "b1"
```

I'm sorry that I can't provide more code or any idea of a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
x <- c("A",  "B",  "C",  "D;", "1",  "2;", "a1", "a2", "a3")

sapply(split(x, c(0, cumsum(grepl(";", x))[-length(x)])), function(x) gsub(";", "", x))

$`0`
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

$`1`
[1] "1" "2"

$`2`
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
```

We use the `cumsum()` of condition `grepl(";", x)` to create a vector for subsetting with `split()`, then remove the semicolons by `sapply()`ing `gsub()`.

Comment: I answered before realizing your answer was really close :). You can make it a bit more compact: `split(sub(";","",s),cumsum(c(0,head(grepl(";",s),-1))))`

Answer (score 3):

I like @LAP's as well, here's another option:

```
vec <- c("A", "B", "C", "D;", "1", "2;", "a1", "a2", "a3;", "b1")

ix <- grep(";", vec)

mapply(function(x, ix1, ix2) x[ix1:ix2], 
       x = list(sub(";", "", vec)),
       ix1 = c(1, ix + 1),
       ix2 = c(ix, length(vec)))

[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[2]]
[1] "1" "2"

[[3]]
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3"

[[4]]
[1] "b1"
```

You'll notice most people are giving you answers that result in a list of vectors, rather than a handful of vectors assigned to variable names. It's generally much cleaner and easier to work with lists of objects rather than objects scattered around in your namespace. Just an added $.02.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, based on the idea of first joining on a space then successively splitting, first on `;` and then on a space:

```
s <- c("A",  "B",  "C",  "D;", "1" , "2;" ,"a1", "a2", "a3")
s <- paste0(s,collapse = ' ')
s <- unlist(strsplit(s, ';'))
vectors <- lapply(s,function(x) unlist(strsplit(trimws(x),' ')))

> vectors
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[2]]
[1] "1" "2"

[[3]]
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing in a tidyverse approach that works in a single pipe.

Similar to other answers, collapse the vector into a single string, then split that string on each `;`. I'm using a space as the collapse so I can use `str_trim` easily later on.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x %>%
  paste(collapse = " ") %>%
  strsplit(split = ";", fixed = T)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A B C D E" " 1 2"      " a1 a2 a3" " b1"
```

Since `strsplit` gives you a list and, at least in this scenario, you're only interested in the first list entry, pull it out with `[[` and trim the beginning and trailing spaces of those vectors. The `map` gives you a list of vectors of one string each.

```r
x %>%
  paste(collapse = " ") %>%
  strsplit(split = ";", fixed = T) %>%
  `[[`(1) %>%
  map(str_trim)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A B C D E"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "1 2"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "a1 a2 a3"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "b1"
```

Then split each vector by the spaces, and flatten into one list of vectors.

All in one pipe:

```r
x %>%
  paste(collapse = " ") %>%
  strsplit(split = ";", fixed = T) %>%
  `[[`(1) %>%
  map(str_trim) %>%
  map(str_split, " ") %>%
  flatten()
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "1" "2"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "b1"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>